# Network error since power outage on a battery

Tags: networking

This is a weird one. I had a little power outage and one of my headless Ubuntu server is not longer connecting to internet. All I see is these logs poppint every like 15 seconds

```
r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: rtl_txcfg_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 666, delay: 100)
```

The weird thing is that this server is on a battery. It didn’t shutdown anyhow. I did rebooted since, no fix.

I tried to do

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/{device_path}/remove
```

As [read here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909213/ethernet-fails-to-initialize), but all I get is permission denied, either in sudo or logged as root. In `rescue` target, I managed to run it, didn't seemed to change anything.

I am a little lost right now, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Thanks to u/Four_Kay on [my initial post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/10egxu0/probleme_since_power_outage/) he helped me realized that maybe that wasn't related to the server. It was not.

I started by isolating the problematic switch port, the one to my upstair switch driving my living room which I have an 4 devices on. I noticed that both the Apple TV and the SteamDeck's Dock were flashing like crazy. I unplug the AppleTV from Ethernet, no change. I unplugged the SteamDeck's dock from Ethernet, no change. I unplugged it from power, and plugged it back with ethernet, never came back.

My understanding is that the Dock wasn't happy with the power loss, the SteamDeck wasn't connected on it too so I think the Dock just became in a weird state flooding the whole network.